# Svn subversion Error while creating new repository on server from client

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, svn-repository

while trying to create a new repository or creating a new folder under current repository using subclipse in eclipse, i am getting an exception

`org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Authorization failed
svn: Authorization failed`

I am using ip address to communicate with server, both client and server connected on same network.
`svn://192.168.1.40/newRepo`

[image: ScreenSot of Error Shown In Eclipse]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a new repository on a server from the client.  Repositories can only be created on the server itself or with a third party app like Subversion Edge that provides a web interface or something else for creating the repositories.

You can create a folder in an existing repository though. Your problem is clearly stated in the error you showed.  Authorization failed.  So this implies whatever user you provided as credentials to authenticate with the server did not have authorization to access it.

Chapters 5 and 6 of the SVNBook are very useful for setting up a server:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/index.html